# How could I match submitted array fields with the MYSQL database fields to update them correctly in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database table with the following schema and would like to update it correctly when a booking form is submitted with the correct matching ticket type and ticket values:

| listing_id | regular_ticket | _other_ticket[0][name] | _other_ticket[1][name] | regular_ticket_sold | _other_ticket[0][sold] | _other_ticket[1][sold] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 149 | regular-ticket | solo-ticket | group-ticket | 5 | 2 | 1 |

The array being posted after submitting the form could look like this(**when buying all the ticket types**):

`{\"listing_id\":\"149\",\"date_start\":\"2023-04-28\",\"date_end\":\"2023-04-28\",\"tickets\":[{\"ticket\":\"regular-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"ticket\":\"solo-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"ticket\":\"group-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}`

And like this when a user selects only **one ticket type**:

`{\"listing_id\":\"149\",\"date_start\":\"2023-04-28\",\"date_end\":\"2023-04-28\",\"tickets\":[{\"ticket\":\"solo-ticket\",\"value\":\"1\"}]}`

**What I have tried:**

```
// update tickets sold
function update_ticket_sold( $tickets, $listing_id )
    {
        $countable = array_column($tickets,'value'); //get ticket count from array
        $other_tickets = get_post_meta( $listing_id, '_other_tickets', true);
        
        if (!empty($tickets[0]['ticket']) && $tickets[0]['ticket'] == 'regular-ticket') {
           //$tickets_count =  (float) $countable[0];
           $already_sold_tickets = (int) get_post_meta($listing_id,'regular_ticket_sold',true);
           $sold_now = $already_sold_tickets + (float) $countable[0];
           update_post_meta($listing_id,'regular_ticket_sold',$sold_now);
           }

        if(isset($other_tickets) && is_array(($other_tickets))){
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($other_tickets as $key => $ticket) {
               if(in_array(($ticket['sold']),array_column($tickets,'sold'))) {
                    $column = '_other_tickets[][sold]';
                    $already_sold_tickets = (int) get_post_meta($listing_id,$column,true);
                    $sold_now = $already_sold_tickets + (float) $countable[$i];
                    update_post_meta($listing_id,$column,$sold_now);
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

- **regular_ticket** ticket type to update values in **regular_ticket_sold**
- **_other_ticket[0][name]** ticket type should update value in **_other_ticket[0][sold]** and
- **_other_ticket[1][name]** to **_other_ticket[1][sold]**

When the regular ticket is selected, the functions updates the database correctly but when any of the other ticket types are selected they never get updated and I get Error: Warning: Undefined array key 1 and Warning: Undefined array key 2

I have been stuck for weeks with this problem. Kindly point me in the right way.

**Update:**

This is what I have narrowed to, the only challenge I am having is in mapping the right ticket type with the corresponding ticket value. For example if **no** solo-ticket is bought and a group-ticket is bought, the group-ticket value gets wrongly pushed to the solo-ticket. Help match it correctly.

```
function update_ticket_sold( array $tickets, $_other_tickets )
    {
        $countable = array_column($tickets,'value'); //get ticket count from array
        $other_tickets = $_other_tickets;

            if(isset($other_tickets) && is_array(($other_tickets))){
                foreach (array_values($other_tickets) as $i => $ticket) {

                        $column = '_other_tickets[ {$i}][sold]';
                        $already_sold_tickets = 0;
                        $sold_now = $already_sold_tickets + (float) $countable[$i];
                        
                        echo "Debug Objects: " . $i . ":" . $ticket['name'] . " = " . $countable[$i] . " Sold: " . $sold_now . "\n";
                    
                }
            }
    }


// Sample arrays used
// Dynamic Tickets as selected by user
$tickets = [
    array (
      "ticket" => "solo-ticket",
      "value" => "0"
    ),
    array (
      "ticket" => "group-ticket",
      "value" => "1"
    )
  ];

// Dynamic Other Ticket types set in the database  
$_other_tickets = [
    array (
      "name" => "solo-ticket",
      "value" => "1"
    ),
    array (
      "name" => "group-ticket",
      "value" => "1"
    )
  ];
  
// Run function
print_r(update_ticket_sold($tickets, $_other_tickets ));
```

Comment: I assume this is a wordpress site ?

Comment: Yes Lee, its a function for wordpress site

Comment: _"The array being posted after submitting the form could look like this"_ - so this would be what the `$tickets` variable passed to your function contains? Not sure what you'd want with `$tickets[0]` then? That JSON data stripped of the extra slashes, and then decoded, would result in a stdClass object or an associative array.

Comment: `$tickets[0]` is used to check if the ticket is a regular ticket whose field is known before `_other_tickets`. Other tickets are named `solo-ticket` , `group-ticket` and are dynamically generated by users. Running `foreach ($other_tickets as $key => $ticket)` iterates through the dynamic _other_tickets_ in the DB so as that we can match them with the tickets submitted through the `$tickets` variable passed to the function. If there is a match, we then update the ticket type/s with the corresponding value/s.